# Preserve types when doing json_encode

Tags: php, json

json_encode does not preserver doubles without numbers after comma

```
echo json_encode(['a' => 4.0]);
{"a":4}
```

How to force json_encode to do this?

```
echo json_encode(['a' => 4.0]);
{"a":4.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this

```
 echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION);
```

Comment: add some more info

Answer (score 0):

add `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION` optional parameter when you are encoding your data as

```
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION);
```